# Python - matplotlib, pyplot, x and y errorbars the wrong way round?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am confused by the order of arguments to `plt.errorbar`

I have the following code in my Python script

```
plt.errorbar(0.0, 1.0, 0.1, 10.0)
```

I would assume the order of arguments is: x_data, y_data, x_error, y_error

This agrees with: http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html

However, when I run this code I get the following output:

[image: Screenshot]

Clearly, x=0.0, y=1.0, x_err=10.0, y_err=0.1

So the x_error and y_error arguments are swapped!

My question is why? Is the documentation wrong? I am so confused!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use keywords, the order of the arguments is `x, y, yerr, xerr`.

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar):

> Call signature:
>
> ```
> errorbar(x, y, yerr=None, xerr=None,
>      fmt='', ecolor=None, elinewidth=None, capsize=None,
>      barsabove=False, lolims=False, uplims=False,
>      xlolims=False, xuplims=False, errorevery=1,
>      capthick=None)
> ```

To avoid this, you can use the keywords to make sure you are giving the correct value to the correct argument; then the order doesn't matter. Note that this is how the example you linked to does it too.

So, for your example, you would want to use:

```
plt.errorbar(0.0, 1.0, xerr=0.1, yerr=10.0)
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know I could re-order arguments in Python!

Comment: @user3728501 you have to name them if you want to reorder them. (In my opinion, you should always name them)